# Store a xml inside a compiled DLL

Tags: c#, xml, configuration

I want to store configuration information about my DLL in an XML file inside my DLL i.e. if changes need to be made the DLL must be re-compiled.

The reason is because its a elegant format and I may not use config files for this DLL.

Any ideas?  I literally want to be able to edit an xml in Visual Studio then compile it and only see a DLL in the output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yup - include it as an Embedded Resource (i.e. use that setting in the Properties for the item in Visual Studio), then use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) to read it.

I do this all the time for unit test data. As you say, you can just edit the file, rebuild, and it'll be there.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make a small addendum to [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373965/store-a-xml-inside-a-compiled-dll/1373970#1373970/). Embedded Resource is the value of the Build Action property on the Properties panel.